# Grouped cumulative sum in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset like this:

```
ID  VAL
A   1
A   4
A   3
B   1
B   2
B   2
```

I want to add a column that gets me the cumulative sum of val per ID such as, preferably with Tidyverse functions, unless Base has something better.

```
ID  VAL CUM
A   1   8 
A   4   8
A   3   8
B   1   5
B   2   5
B   2   5
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, you can perform a `sum` on grouped `ID`

```r
library(dplyr)
df =data.frame(ID = c(rep("A",3),rep("B",3)),
               VAL = c(1,4,3,1,2,2))

df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(CUM = sum(VAL))

# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   ID [2]
  ID      VAL   CUM
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A         1     8
2 A         4     8
3 A         3     8
4 B         1     5
5 B         2     5
6 B         2     5
```